# Keycloak multi-tenants/realms

Tags: keycloak

I have a case with two separate applications living next to each other. Each has its own Keycloak with a realm on it. The problem starts with embedding one application into another and to avoid double authentication.

The only solution I can think of is having one Keycloak as "Main" that during the authentication process will generate token that can be used for both applications. There should be some link between these Keycloaks. But how to setup such delegation?

Based on Keycloak documentation its multi-tenant with multi-realms. I won't be able to simplify the setup to have one tenant/realm as there are different teams involved in managing those.

In short words what I want - **I want Main Keycloak to be able to authenticate users to itself and delegated Keycloak so it will return token accepted by apps configured for either one or second Keycloak**.

Any tips or thought would be great!

Edit:
I found something about Token-Exchange, but any feedback from advanced people would be appreciated!